# WatchKit Extension Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to send my iOS app to the App Store right now. It compiles fine and installs onto my test device without a single error or even warning. I have an Apple Watch App that is going to go along with it but it seems to be giving me problems. When I create the Archive of the app, I get the following 5 warnings:

```
[App Name] WatchKit Extension

warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/***/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/*** Watch App.app/_WatchKitStub/WK

warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/***/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/*** Watch App.app/*** Watch App


[App Name]

warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/***/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/*** WatchKit Extension.appex/*** Watch App.app/_WatchKitStub/WK

warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/***/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/*** WatchKit Extension.appex/*** Watch App.app/*** Watch App

warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/***/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/*** WatchKit Extension.appex/*** WatchKit Extension
```

And then it's proceeded with this error:

[image: From Xcode v6.3]

Anyone else having these issues? Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: FYI - I put asterisks to cover up any personal information above and cropped out any names. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: Have you setup an appstore provisioning profile for the watch extension?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I have one for the app (obviously :] ) and I set one up for the WatchKit App. I thought I needed one for the Extension but when I copy the Bundle ID for the extension from Xcode and I paste it into a new prov. profile in the developer portal, it says it's an invalid name. I thought it probably wouldn't take anything ending in .watchkitextension. Am I wrong on this? If this is the case, then I have to contact Apple because as far as Im concerned, the bundle IDs have to be similar to the App Bundle ID (Same Prefix).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29529019/2210682) I wrote yesterday

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watchkit Extension - No matchin provisioning profiles found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816339/watchkit-extension-no-matchin-provisioning-profiles-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had both of these problems when I created my WatchKit app.

(1) For your first problem: warning: skipping copy phase strip.

I found the solutions here:

[Warning during archive App with iOS 8 Extension in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949108/warning-during-archive-app-with-ios-8-extension-in-xcode-6)

and here:

[Xcode 6 Archiving and get a warning "Skipping copy phase strip ,binary is code signed" when add "share extension" to target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401247/xcode-6-archiving-and-get-a-warning-skipping-copy-phase-strip-binary-is-code-s)

Specifically, here are the steps I used to fix the problem:

1. Start Xcode and open your project.
2. Select the blue project icon in the upper-left-hand corner.
3. In second column that contains sections: PROJECT and TARGETS,
   select your main target under the TARGETS section.
4. Select the “Build Settings” tab.
5. Scroll down to the “Deployment” section.
6. Find and expand the section called “Strip Debug Symbols During Copy”
7. Find the row called "Release".
8. Change the value from "Yes" to "No".

[image: Build Settings > Deployment > Strip Debug Symbols]

(2) For your second problem: Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets
The solutions are here:

[No matching provisioning profiles found for WatchKit extension when submitting to App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544427/no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-for-watchkit-extension-when-submitting-t)

and here:

[Submit WatchKit Provisioning Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479139/submit-watchkit-provisioning-error)

I had to regenerate the "Distribution" Provisioning Profile that I was using to submit my entire app, before I included the WatchKit extension. Specifically, these steps fixed my problem:

I logged onto developer.apple.com, selected "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

1. On the Certs IDs & Profiles website > Provisioning Profiles page, click the App Store profile.
2. Click 'Edit'
3. Click 'Generate'

Comment: So for the first step you listed about "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" didn't work until I got your second step to work. I'm not sure why, they seem somewhat unrelated. The second step was that Xcode had generated a provisioning profile for me without me knowing (my fault) and gave it some unusual name (which is why I would miss it every time I would go into the dev portal). When I looked carefully, I saw it and recreated it with a name I wanted. It worked and it caused the first step to work too! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I did not expect that the second step would help resolve the first step, but I am glad it is working for you now.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution that worked (for me)

First: Just make sure that you enabled all services that you used on your app on your (Watch Kit App) and (Watch Kit Extension),

For example if you used iCloud on your native app, you should enable iCloud on your (Watch Kit App) and (Watch Kit Extension) even if you didn't use iCloud on your watch app.

Same goes for app groups..

Second: Make sure the bundle identifier on (Watch Kit App) and (Watch Kit Extension) has to extend the native app,

For example if the app `com.company.myapp` the (Watch Kit App) identifier should be: `com.company.myapp.watchkitapp` and on (Watch Kit Extension) should be: `com.company.myapp.watchkitextension`

Hope this helps.