# How to avoid "skipping copy phase strip" warning (because "binary is code signed”) without setting "strip debug symbols during copy" to NO?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, debug-symbols

When performing an archive build with "strip debug symbols during copy" set to YES, I get the warning "skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed". 
The generally suggested solution on threads regarding this issue is to set "strip debug symbols during copy" to NO. 
Sure that get's rid of the warning, but I don't think the approach to remove the "low oil warning light" will solve the underlying issue.

It seems the size of the binary can get bloated when this option is set to NO. And also why would you want to ship debug symbols with your app?

I would appreciate tips, insights and optimally a solution.

Comment: The warning "skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed" occurs for  own frameworks as well as for iOS 8 extensions, which are both code signed (seems to be required).

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Xcode doesn't detect that the code signed framework is already stripped. The warning is harmless.

Comment: But it is really annoying, especially when you link against many own frameworks, Xcode spams you with dozens of such warnings, making it harder to see the really important warnings. There should really be a way to turn those off. As the OP already said, disabling "Strip debug symbols during copy" is not a solution.

Comment: Spam hides real issues so it requires more time and effort to manually go through the issues list, can't say it's "harmless" unless the whole team just don't care about warnings at all.

Answer (score 1):

The size of your shipped binary will not be influenced by this setting. That is another setting, named "Strip Linked Product". You can leave that set to YES. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7915911/923288

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to go into the General tab of your app, scroll down to "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content", find the offending library that should be in that list and change "Embed & Sign" into "Do Not Embed", this will certainly get rid of the warning and the app would work on the simulator fine, however, depending on how the lib was coded it's not 100% guaranteed that it would work on the device (being debugged through Xcode), apart from that it should work fine.

H